# How can i combine array into Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have an array with 100 member number.

I will now check check my database has these membership numbers, if yes, then insert "card" in a particular field.

This is my array

```
 $myArray=array("10309,
10404,
10515,
10544,
10587,
10749,
10778,
10905,
11001,
11007,
11060,
11450,
11628,
11701,
11747,
11908,
");
```

This is mysql statement

```
UPDATE exp_member_data as emd
set emd.m_field_id_25 = 'card'
where emd.member_id = **10309**
```

But how can i combine it with my array? This is how i tried.

```
foreach ($myArray as $key) 
{
        UPDATE exp_member_data as emd
    set emd.m_field_id_25 = 'card'
    where emd.member_id = '$key'
}
```

Is there a simpler way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [implode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) to join array elements with comma.

```
$myArrayString = implode(", ", $myArray);

UPDATE exp_member_data as emd
set emd.m_field_id_25 = 'card'
where emd.member_id in ($myArrayString)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use combination of in clause and php's [implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) function

```
$implodedString = implode(",", $myArray);

"UPDATE exp_member_data as emd   set emd.m_field_id_25 = 'card'   where emd.member_id  IN($implodedString)";
```